# TCPDI Uninitialized string offset: 35

Tags: php, pdf, png

У меня есть код который с помощью библиотеки TCPDI добавляет png изображение в pdf документ. Но если PDF объемом больше 1мб то возникает ошибка Uninitialized string offset: 35
Вот мой код:

````
        $pdf = new TCPDI(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, 'px', PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
        $lists = $pdf->setSourceFile($file_dir);
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
        for($i=1; $i<=$lists; $i++) {
            $import = $pdf->importPage($i);
            $size = $pdf->getTemplatesize($import);
            $pdf->AddPage($size['w'] > $size['h'] ? 'L' : 'P');
            $pdf->useTemplate($import, 0, 0);
            if($i==$lists){
                $res = getimagesize(stream_get_meta_data($this->sign)['uri']);
                $pdf->SetY(-$res[1] / 2 - 10);
                $pdf->SetX(-$res[0] / 2 - 10); 
                $pdf->Image(stream_get_meta_data($this->sign)['uri'], $pdf->getX(), $pdf->getY(), $res[0] / 2, $res[1] / 2);
            }
        }

        $tmp = tmpfile();
        file_put_contents(stream_get_meta_data($tmp)['uri'], file_get_contents($file_dir));
        $pdf->output(stream_get_meta_data($tmp)['uri'], 'D');
        return base64_encode(file_get_contents(stream_get_meta_data($tmp)['uri']));```

Вот мой конфиг php.ini

max_execution_time           = 60
max_input_vars              = 5000
memory_limit                 = -1
post_max_size                = 128M
upload_max_filesize          = 50M

Помогите пожалуйста.
````

Comment: Видимо ошибка в коде библиотеки, заполните [Issue Report](https://github.com/pauln/tcpdi/issues)